# Supervisor : can't terminate a child by pid

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

Trying to terminate a child by its pid does not work, it should according to the documentation : https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.3.3/Supervisor.html#terminate_child/2

```
iex(7)> {:ok, sup} = Supervisor.start_link([], strategy: :one_for_one)                           
{:ok, #PID<0.383.0>}
iex(8)> {:ok, pid} = Supervisor.start_child(sup, worker(RData.ExpectedRefurbishmentCost, [self()]))
{:ok, #PID<0.385.0>}
iex(9)> Supervisor.terminate_child(sup, pid)                                                       
{:error, :not_found}
```

Any clues to make it work ?

Comment: The documentation says you need to pass the child id for all strategies except `simple_one_for_one`. PID only works for `simple_one_for_one`.

Comment: I passed beyond that... thx for the precision :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the child id to `terminate_child` for all strategies except `:simple_one_for_one`. So, for `:one_for_one`, the following should work for you since the `id` is set to the module by `Supervisor.Spec.worker/3` if one is not provided:

```
Supervisor.terminate_child(sup, RData.ExpectedRefurbishmentCost)
```